# java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '2'

Tags: java, exception

I keep receiving this conversion error:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '2'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at BookTest.main(BookTest.java:40)
```

This is the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
double total = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<quantityArray.length; i++)
    {
        message += String.format("%s %s $%2.f", bookArray[i].getTitle(), bookArray[i].getIsbn(), bookArray[i].calculateCharge(quantityArray[i]));
        total += bookArray[i].calculateCharge(quantityArray[i]);
    }

    message += String.format("Total is: $%2.f", total);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) is:

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

As you can see, a `.` *must* be followed by a `precision` value.

Your value (`%2.f`) is not valid.
If you want to output as `$123.45`, you need to flip the `2` and the `.`: `%.2f`

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the %2.f parameter. You probably want something like

```
String.format ("Total is: $%5.2f", total);
```

In this example 5 is the total width of the field (including the decimal point), and two is the number of decimal places.